# Which command locks screen with lightDM?

Tags: lightdm, lock-screen

I used to lock screen with this command, but it stopped working recently, probably after update. I'm running `VERSION="13.10, Saucy Salamander"`. How can I restore this function?

```
$ gdmflexiserver
method return sender=:1.10 -> dest=:1.97 reply_serial=2
```

I used to invoke this command with openbox keybinding:

```
<keybind key="XF86ScreenSaver">
  <action name="Execute">
    <execute>gdmflexiserver</execute>
  </action>
```

I think it used to work from terminal emulator as well.

UPDATE:
To my surprise, it works again. This might be because of system update.

```
method return sender=:1.10 -> dest=:1.71 reply_serial=2
```

Answer (score 24):

What @wilf said, but maybe you are looking for

```
dm-tool lock
```

for a different lock experience. (Because you said *with lightDM*...)

**SECURITY WARNING**: avoid using dm-tool lock unless you can verify it works correctly, see:

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=740163
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxsession/+bug/1205384

Comment: Running this from a `tty`, and this is for a display manger I couldn't use `export display=..`, I got this error: `Not running inside a display manager, XDG_SEAT_PATH not defined`. Also, don't be daft like me and run `dm-tool lock` in a terminal when you are logged in ;D

Comment: @wilf I don't know whether he wants to do it from a `tty`? But with something like `XDG_SEAT_PATH="/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0" dm-tool lock` it should work (as the error suggests). (Check your XDG_SEAT_PATH in the gui with `echo $XDG_SEAT_PATH`) Though this dm-tool method is kinda broken in my 12.04 as if I lock the screen with it, then switch to `tty`, then switch back, the screen is unlocked. :D I don't know if this is corrected in 13.10. That's why I said your method is the one and gave an up for it. (Just that method isn't related to lightdm, so maybe the OP is looking for this)

Comment: `dm-tool lock` has no effect, but it can list Seat0 so I guess it should work.

Comment: @Rumca I looked [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1205384) for a bugreport. You said openbox, so I guess you are using Lubuntu, which accordingly to that bugreport also suffers from the problem which I mentioned in my previous comment: The lock can be easily circumvented. I've just read into the conversation under that bugreport and I have the impression that you will have to install a screensaver to lock the screen. Looks like locking of the screen was never secure on Lubuntu and now the developers removed the previous lock possibility because of that.

Comment: @Rumca But please read the conversation under the bugreport, I had no time to read through it.

Answer (score 2):

Just this normally works, but with `gdm` *(Gnome Desktop Manager)*:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

If this is from a `tty`, you need to run `export display=:0` or something first - you can find the current user session using `w`.

*I think I'll just leave this in for reference*

Answer (score 0):

Install light-locker. The command:

```
dm-tool lock
```

or:

```
light-locker-command -l
```

Should then lock the screen, using the lightdm greeter as the lock-screen. If you try to switch back with the tty you will just get a locked screen with a message and then get redirected to the greeter after a few seconds.