# Automatic screen lock not working Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, lock-screen

From *Settings -> Privacy*, I got

- *Automatic Screen lock -> turned on*
- *Lock Screen on Suspend -> turned on*

None of them locks my screen. But the manual lock option works fine. (I did get some error message about Auto-lock while installation)

Any thoughts on how to fix it? And I'm using ***lightdm*** instead of gnome-gdm3

Comment: `Auto-lock`?  Is this a package you installed?

Comment: No. I meant the installation of ubuntu-20.04. And got an error message about auto-lock functionality but didn't understand.

Comment: error msg you got during lightdm installation??

Comment: Got error while upgrading to ubuntu-20.04 from 19.10. And by default I use lightdm.

Comment: I am trying gnome-screensaver with my updated ubuntu-20.04/gnome/lightdm.

Comment: see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242110/after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04-lockscreen-not-working#comment2169887_1242290)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screen lock is disabled by default with lightdm on Ubuntu 18+ due security issues.

check more here:

- [SO original question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407748/which-command-locks-screen-with-lightdm)
- [Bug on launchpad #1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxsession/+bug/1205384)
- [Bug on launchpad #2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxsession/+bug/1205384)
- or just try yourself: lock screen, press `CTRL+ALT+F7`  and you will
  be back on your desktop without providing a password

You can check you display manager with: `sudo systemctl status display-manager`

If you still want to lock your screen with lightdm - you can use `dm-tool lock`. Also you can add it to keyboard shortcut as command (e.g. `Super+L`).

Switching to gdm3 helped: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`

Comment: Switching to gdm3 worked. Be aware though, when you receive an error message that the switch was not successful, you need to restart. That's what did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

What's the timeout set to? Previous experience may point to a very unexpected hardware related cause which I call "mouse jitter": It could be that your mouse has a slight malfunction and 'jiggles' by itself a bit, causing your computer to stay awake. Try unplugging your mouse and see what gives.

Comment: I don't think so.